# Updating view based on selection in a NSTableView in a different view controller

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I have a core data model which has TrainingDiary which has zero of more Days which each have zero or more Workouts. I have a working GUI that has a table for each and works when I select a TrainingDiary it shows the appropriate Days and in turn when I select a Day it shows the workouts. Each table has an Array Controller which has its managed object context bound to the managedObjectContext var in the view controller. Their content set is bound to the Array Controller selection. i.e.
Days Array controller is bound to the selection of the Training Diary AC
Workouts Array Controller is bound to the selection of the Days AC
The tables are then bound to the arrangedObjects of the relevant Array Controller.

With this working I need to change my GUI so that the TrainingDiary table sits in a different ViewController so that when I select a training diary I update various views for that selection. This is needed as the GUI is getting more complex now and I need to break things out.

I have a Main view controller which has a Table view showing the TrainingDiaries. It also has a Container view which has a Tab View Controller embedded in it. Each tab will show a different part of the TrainingDiary thats selected in the table. I’m trying to get the first tab to show the table of days that I had working already in the single view controller version.

I just can’t get the tab views to update based on the selection in the Training Diary table.

I’ve tried

1. To mimic how it worked all in one ViewController - i.e. to bind the Days AC to the selection of the Training Diary AC. However now they’re in different views this does not appear to be an option.
2. I added an Observer on the Training Diary AC selection. I add the observer in the viewDidLoad method of the Main View Controller. I’ve implemented observeValue in there which sets the selected trainingDiary as the trainingDiary in the underlying view (NB TrainingDiary is an auto generated class from the Core Data entity TrainingDiary:

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       guard let tabViewController = segue.destinationController
       as? NSTabViewController else { return }

       for controller in tabViewController.childViewControllers {

           if let controller = controller as? DaysViewController {
               daysViewController = controller
           }
       }
   }

   override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
       print("observe value called")
       daysViewController?.trainingDiary = (trainingDiaryAC.selectedObjects[0] as! TrainingDiary)
   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       trainingDiaryAC.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "selectionIndex", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
   }
   ```

This feels the right way to do it but now the GUI doesn’t update when the selection changes. i.e. when the training diary selection is changed the Days table doesn’t update. However if I add an item to the table then it all displays. I tried setting needsDisplay to true on the view controllers NSView ( even tried looping through the subviews as well):

```
@objc public var trainingDiary: TrainingDiary?{
    didSet{
        print("Setting Training Diary")
        self.view.needsDisplay = true
        for v in self.view.subviews{
            v.needsDisplay = true
        }
    }
}
```

But that doesn’t work either. By setting the trainingDiary I seem to have circumvented all the notifications that seem to come with Core Data.

So my questions

1. Am I on the right track with either of the above approaches.
2. I’m hoping there’s a pretty standard way to achieve what I’m trying to do. Is someone able to illustrate the approach ?

[I'm using SWIFT 4 and XCode 9]

Comment: [Cocoa Bindings in OS X Storyboards](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1871/_index.html)